# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing a piece of code which displays in an expandable list using information from an AsyncTask and a pre defined HashMap. But it is throwing **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**. My code is as follows:

AsnycTask

```
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        ArrayList<String> name;
        ArrayList<Integer> quantity;
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cart_names1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

        public BackTask(ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<Integer> quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(ha);

            pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");

            pd.setMessage("Please wait.");

            pd.setCancelable(true);

            pd.setIndeterminate(true);

            pd.show();


        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                String link = "http://chutte.co.nf/get_item_prices.php?";
                for (int b = 0; b < name.size(); b++) {
                    link += "names[]" + "=" + name.get(b) + "&";

                }
                for (int a = 0; a < quantity.size(); a++) {
                    link += "quantities[]" + "=" + quantity.get(a);
                    if (a != quantity.size() - 1) {
                        link += "&";
                    }
                }
                Log.e("ERROR", link);
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (pd != null) pd.dismiss();


                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");

                }
                is.close();
                result = builder.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                result = result.substring(result.indexOf("["));
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Map<String, Integer> temmap = new HashMap<>();
                    String temname = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                    temmap.put("First", jsonObject.getInt("First"));
                    temmap.put("Second", jsonObject.getInt("Second"));
                    temmap.put("Third", jsonObject.getInt("Third"));
                    Log.e("ERROR", temmap.get("First").toString());
                    cart_names1.put(temname, temmap);

                }
                strhold2.clear();
                strhold2.add("First");
                strhold2.add("Second");
                strhold2.add("Third");


                String[] strhold1 = new String[strhold2.size()];
                for (int i56 = 0; i56 < strhold2.size(); i56++) {
                    strhold1[i56] = strhold2.get(i56);
                }
                System.out.println(cart_names1);
                Log.e("ERROR", Integer.toString(cart_names1.size()) + "IN LATEST");
                if (cart_names1.size() > 1) {
                    System.out.println(cart_names1.size());
                    System.out.println(strhold2.size());
                    Combination.printCombination(cart_names1, strhold1, strhold2.size(), cart_names1.size(), 2);
                    ArrayList<String> wrong = Permutation.getlist();
                    System.out.println(wrong + "this is final");
                    setalldata(wrong);
                    System.out.println(wrong);
                    couldthis.clear();
                    couldthis.addAll(wrong);
                } else {
                    Single_Permutation.getpermute(cart_names1);
                    System.out.println(Single_Permutation.singlelist);
                    couldthis.clear();
                    couldthis.addAll(Single_Permutation.singlelist);
                    setalldata(Single_Permutation.singlelist);
                    Log.e("ERROR", "thisis the list 1" + getdataformap());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            /*SetMap setMap = new SetMap(getdataformap());
            setMap.execute();*/
            if (pd != null){ pd.dismiss();}
               ListFragment.addtolist(getdataformap());
                Log.e("ERROR", "This is putmap i" + getdataformap());
                SetMap setMap =new SetMap(getdataformap());
                setMap.execute();
            }
        }

    }
```

Fragment(with expandable list)

```
public static class ListFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static ExpandableListView expandablelistview;
        public static CustomExpandableListAdapter expandableadapter;
        public static HashMap<Fitems, List<Fnitems>> datapforput = new HashMap<>();
        public static List<Fitems> mainforput = new ArrayList<>();
        public static View view;
        public static Context getha;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listfragment, container, false);
            //doddata();
            expandablelistview = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
            expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(((Result) getActivity()).getha(), mainforput, datapforput);
            expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);
            getha = ((Result) getActivity()).getha();
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Permutation.finallist = new ArrayList<>();
            Single_Permutation.singlelist = new ArrayList<>();
   /* doddata();
    expandablelistview = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(((Result)getActivity()).getha(),mainforput,datapforput);
    expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);*/
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static void doddata() {
            Fitems fitems1 = new Fitems();
            Fitems fitems2 = new Fitems();
            Fnitems fnitems1 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems2 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems3 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems4 = new Fnitems();
            fitems1.setName("AAA");
            fitems2.setName("BBB");
            fnitems1.setName("AAAa");
            fnitems2.setName("AAAb");
            fnitems3.setName("BBBa");
            fnitems4.setName("BBBb");
            List<Fnitems> listfnitem1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Fnitems> listfnitem2 = new ArrayList<>();
            listfnitem1.add(fnitems1);
            listfnitem1.add(fnitems2);
            listfnitem2.add(fnitems3);
            listfnitem2.add(fnitems4);
            datapforput.put(fitems1, listfnitem1);
            datapforput.put(fitems2, listfnitem2);
            mainforput.add(fitems1);
            mainforput.add(fitems2);
            //Log.e("ERROR", "thisis the list for god's sake " + Result.couldthis+datapforput.toString());
            if (Result.couldthis.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < (Result.couldthis).size(); i++) {
                    for (Map.Entry<Fitems, List<Fnitems>> entry : datapforput.entrySet()) {
                        if (Result.couldthis.get(i).equals(entry.getKey().getName())){
                            Fnitems fnitems5 = new Fnitems();
                            fnitems5.setName(Search_multiple.cart_records.get(i).getName());
                            entry.getValue().add(fnitems5);
                        }else {
                            Fitems fitems3 = new Fitems();
                            fitems3.setName(Result.couldthis.get(i));
                            Fnitems fnitems5 = new Fnitems();
                            fnitems5.setName(Search_multiple.cart_records.get(i).getName());
                            List<Fnitems> listfnitem3 = new ArrayList<>();
                            listfnitem3.add(fnitems5);
                            datapforput.put(fitems3, listfnitem3);
                            mainforput.add(fitems3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static ListFragment newInstance() {
            ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
            Log.e("ERROR", "man .... " + fragment.getTag());
            return fragment;
        }

        public static void addtolist(ArrayList<String> dataforputting) {
           // Log.e("ERROR", "thisis the list 3" + (dataforputting));
            //if (expandableadapter != null){
            expandableadapter.clear();//}
            //Log.e("INFO", "This is mainforput" + mainforput + "This is dataforput" + datapforput);
            doddata();
            //Log.e("INFO", "This is mainforput" + mainforput + "This is dataforput" + datapforput);
            expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getha, mainforput, datapforput);
            expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);
        }


    }
```

Stack

```
07-13 18:16:11.955 17339-17339/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/ERROR: Inside populate Second
07-13 18:16:11.986 17339-17339/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: nf.co.riaah.chutte, PID: 17339
                                                                    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:824)
                                                                        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:822)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment.doddata(Result.java:199)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment.addtolist(Result.java:230)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$SetMap.onPostExecute(Result.java:1049)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$SetMap.onPostExecute(Result.java:967)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: Perhaps use a Hashtable instead. HashMap is not safe for concurrent access.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're modifying a collection while trying to iterate over it. It could be all in the same place or it could be from different threads.

Comment: I am familiar with that , but couldn't figure out where it is happening in my code and how i can stop it

Comment: Look through your code and find where you're iterating over collections and look at where you're adding or removing stuff from those collections. Then looks for places where those could be happening at the same time. Unfortunately if you've not tried to keep this in mind from the beginning it's tough to track down.

Comment: I'm iterating at numerous places but on different collections , does that cause a problem???

Comment: Iterating doesn't cause a problem. The problem comes when you try to add and remove stuff from the collection that you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

for each loop are generally fail fast , that you can 't change the collection ( as for each internally use iterator ) .

instead of using " for (Map.Entry> entry : datapforput.entrySet()) "

create an iterator and then iterate over map again , don't forget to  assign 
iterator reference to newly created entrySet . just reassign iterartor reference each time in while / for whichever loop you use to iterate .

}

Comment: how can i do the above (code please) ??